# Geoserver WMS breakpoint

Tags: geoserver, wms, java, request, getmap

I just started developing geoserver extension and i need help about WMS requests.
I want to print hello to the terminal when a WMS request comes. Context of my class:

```
package org.geoserver.wms.cluster;

import org.geoserver.wms.GetMapCallback;
import org.geoserver.wms.GetMapCallbackAdapter;
import org.geoserver.wms.GetMapRequest;
import org.geoserver.wms.WMSMapContent;


public class ClusterGetMapCallbackAdapter extends GetMapCallbackAdapter
        implements GetMapCallback {

    public ClusterGetMapCallbackAdapter() {
    }
    @Override
    public GetMapRequest initRequest(GetMapRequest request) {
        System.out.println("HELLOO");
        return request;
    }
    @Override
    public void initMapContent(WMSMapContent mapContent) {    
        System.out.println("HELLOO");
    }
    @Override
    public WMSMapContent beforeRender(WMSMapContent mapContent) {
        System.out.println("HELLOO");
        return mapContent;
    }
}
```

How can i use these methods? What kind of pom.xml or applicationContext.xml should I write?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - could you describe what you are trying to do as well as what you have tried so far. Can you not just set a break point in your debugger and step through to find out where you are going?